# Trigging tap event jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, tap

I'm pretty new to Jquery Mobile and I'm trying to trig a tap event.
It's working. If I click the div the class will be added. But if I click the a tag the class will be added to the a tag too. 
How can I make the class be added just to the div, no matter if I click the div or a?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="measure-success">
<div class="measures"><a href="">How long to prepare each campaign?</a></div>
<div class="measures"><a href="">Size of Database</a></div>
</div>

$(function() {  
   $("#measure-success .measures").bind("tap", tapHandler);
    function tapHandler (event) {
        $(event.target).addClass("tap");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(event.target)` to `$(this)`  leave the rest of the code as is.